# How to increase the speed of code written in Matlab

Tags: performance, matlab, mex

Mathematica has a feature called `Compile` by compiling your written code in Mathematica languange you turn it into c code and run the resulting code inside Mathematica, it won't give you c code but it turns the code into it and use it. The compiled code gains a lot of speed compared to the uncompiled version.

Is there a similar feature in Matlab so that someone can easily make a code written in Matlab faster without extra effort?

It seems that Matlab compiler doesn't accomplish this goal as indeed it isn't meant to be used for this purpose. 
I don't know about Matlab coder. I just read something about MEX files but to me it seems as if I have to write the code in c and then bring it into Matlab for speed.

Can somebody guide me about this and show a simple example?

Comment: Why a vote down without mentioning the reason?

Comment: What kind of code are you looking to speed up? If it involves math on matrices, it's very unlikely you'll see any speed up from converting it to mex, unless you really know what you're doing.

Comment: It involves the multiplication of forty thousands of matrices as one part of the code. Other than speeding my code, I want to know that if there is the equivalent of `Compile` feature of Mathematica in Matlab.

Comment: You can preparse your functions which reduces their load time significantly, but for more speedup you need to rewrite in C++ or change the approach.

Comment: See [`coder`](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab-coder/) and [`codegen`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ref/codegen.html) (if you have them). [This video](http://www.mathworks.com/videos/generating-c-code-from-matlab-code-68964.html) might be helpful.

Comment: This is a reasonable question and the short answer is: not anymore.  Once there was a capability to automatically make a Mex file from .m and get significant speed gains, but they removed that while the worked in their JIT compiler.  Then that functionality came back as Coder (`codegen`), which is not free and not even necessarily faster, mainly for portability.  Then there's Compiler, which is basically a VM for .m code deployment, and it's the same speed or slower than native MATLAB.  That's it.

Comment: p.s. The speed of a MEX file you write is only as fast as you can code in C/C++ or FORTRAN and how good the compiler is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer: compiling matlab code is not going to get you a much speed up, if any.

The longer answer: 
The **Matlab Compiler** is more for letting you deploy matlab code for use on machines which don't have matlab, rather than for getting a speed up.  In fact, from poking into applications I have deployed with it, it actually wraps up the scripts with a cut down Matlab run-time.  So, if anything this will slow things down due to un-packing and startup times, etc.

Matlab has some fairly good **just-in-time optimization** stuff in it anyway, which takes care of the low hanging fruit in terms of speed up from compilation.  As horchler & chappjc mentioned in the question comments, you could try **`codegen` or `coder`**, however you may not get much better results.

If you want to try to get a speed up by using a **mexFunction**, then you pretty much have to re-write your function in c/c++ or fortran.  Depending on the nature of the problem, your skill with C/C++ and the amount of time you have to spend on it this may end up providing a significantly quicker result as it can take advantage of your compiler's optimization tricks, and a hand coded solution may well cut out certain superfluous elements found in the matlab implementation which are necessary for generalities sake.  Doing this however would break the "without significant effort" critereon.

In terms of low effort methods I would recommend you try boosting the efficiency of your matlab code first by using **profile** to look for bottle-necks or needless repetition, and then try to **vectorize** calculations wherever possible so matlab can automatically parallelize them.

If you still really need a performance boost and are working with [certain matrix functions](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/run-built-in-functions-on-a-gpu.html), then you could look into **Matlab's GPU and CUDA** support.  I haven't done much with it myself yet, however it may be the case that you just have to change some datatypes to gpuArray to gain the benefit of it running on your graphics card (something of a boost for parallel computations).

Comment: MATLAB Compiler and MEX functions are very different things.  And while the JIT is a huge improvement over interpretation, it does not give "most of the speed benefit you would get from compiling".  Not compared to MEX with a good C++ optimizer, anyway.

Comment: @BenVoigt Granted, re-writing one's algorithm in efficient clean c++ and using a compiler with some decent optimisation will give you faster code.  That however is a significant effort and I was considering it in terms of "without much extra effort", as specified in the question.  I will edit my answer to better reflect this, and perhaps mention the possibility of GPGPU measures.